Making combined elements (such as text blocks) in Elementor for WP
I realize these are technically two distinct items but I think they're closely related in how I am doing them wrong.
This is a bar of 5 text blocks, that spans the width of the screen (and is responsive)


I cannot figure out how to make 5 blocks that fit side-by-side, with no whitespace between them. I am trying to use a grid but the content won't expand to fill the blocks.

I cannot figure out how to make the two different text sizes in the same block. I add the number text and enlarge it, then add the rest of the it, but it won't change the font size of just a portion of the text - it changes it all or nothing in that widget. I tried adding them as two separate text editor widgets but it won't allow that. When I try to drop a second widget in the same grid cell, it instead puts it in the next grid cell, as if side-by-side.



